# Looking for a textbook on mathematical statistics at the same level of Casella but with the language of linear algebra

Tags: references

Is there any textbooks on math stats that's at the level of Casella but uses the language of linear algebra and covers the multivariate cases?
Casella is a great book, but he dose not talk about the multivariate normal distribution and does not use matrix algebra, the covariance matrix was not even mentioned in the main content, those are really important in my field (Econometrics).

I am a first year phd student in Econ, right now we are using Hansen's textbook, prob & stats for economists. Hansen's book covers everything I need, covariance matrix, multi norm distribution, multi CLT, but Hansen dose not go into any details. After all, it's a textbook for general economists but I want to specialize in theoretical econometrics. I have a master in pure math but I'm a beginner in stat.

Edit: by Casella's textbook, I'm talking about the statistical inference 2nd edition. I realized he wrote multiple books on stats.

Hogg is also great, he covers multi normal distribution, but he still put the matrix part in star, which I don't really like. Maybe such book do not exists.

Comment: Have you checked Rao's _Linear Statistical Inference and its Applications_? Personally, I am of the opinion that it is not apt for first read.

Comment: @User1865345 I looked up the table of content, I feel like it is too advanced for me.

Comment: I am not sure as to what can be made of your specific demand on linear algebraic language. But if you want formal mathematical treatment: you can start from Rohatgi, Keener, all the way to Shao. As for econometrics, I did enjoy (albeit not read in detail) Amemiya.